# console log not printing from a constructor function

Tags: javascript, class, prototypal-inheritance

There are three classes with inheritance in javascript.  When I remove the super() in the middle class, the child constructor no longer prints the console.log.  But when I put the super() in the middle class, then ALL 3 console logs show up.  Wondering why the missing middle super() cancels out even the child console log.

```
class Great {
    constructor() {
        console.log('this is great');
    }
}

class Grand extends Great {
    constructor() {
        // super();
        console.log('this is grand');
    }
}

class Father extends Grand {
    constructor() {
        super();
        console.log('I am your father');
    }
}

function main() {
    let dad = new Father();
}

main();
```

I would expect the console to show "this is grand" and "I am your father".  but the only thing that shows up is "this is grand" when commenting out the super of the middle class.

Comment: I thought it wasn’t possible to not call `super()` in an inherited class? Are you using a tool to compile ES6 classes to older syntax? Can you show a screenshot of this behaviour?

Comment: Or are you just not mentioning an error that appears after “this is grand”?

Comment: whenever you create a class that inherits from a parent, you have to invoke super() in the constructor of the child to pull the data in from the parent.  I've always done it that way without any errors.

Comment: I also see the error when I try to invoke the code as written-- I think that the error is being encountered before any of the console logging is invoked...

Comment: @AmirYunas: That’s correct. And when you *don’t* invoke `super()` in the constructor of the child, like in the case here where it’s commented out, it’s supposed to throw an error. Do you see an error?

Comment: ```this is grand
inheritance2.js:10 Uncaught ReferenceError: Must call super constructor in derived class before accessing 'this' or returning from derived constructor
    at new Grand (inheritance2.js:10)
    at new Father (inheritance2.js:16)
    at main (inheritance2.js:22)
    at inheritance2.js:25
Grand @ inheritance2.js:10
Father @ inheritance2.js:16
main @ inheritance2.js:22
(anonymous) @ inheritance2.js:25
VM144:140 DomDistiller debug level: 0```

Comment: yes, above is the error, so I guess the reason it doesn't print the child console log is because an error was generated.

Comment: @Amir Yunas: After you call `super` in `Father.constructor`, `Grand.constructor` is called, then the log "this is grand" is shown and you went out of `Grand.constructor` without call `super()` so it throws an error and the code stop executing, that's why the log "I am your father" wasn't show.

Answer (score 1):

```js
class Great {
  constructor() {
    console.log('this is great');
  }
}

class Grand extends Great {
  constructor() {
    // super();
    console.log('this is grand');
  }
}

class Father extends Grand {
  constructor() {
    // calls Grand constructor function and its console.log
    super();
    // ReferenceError: must call super constructor before using 'this' in derived class constructor
    // The Grand constructor throws an error preventing the next line to be executed
    console.log('I am your father');
  }
}

function main() {
  let dad = new Father();
}

main();
```

It is the same as the following:

```js
const functionWithError = () => {
  console.log('I am about to throw');
  throw new Error('Throwing...');
}

const functionThatCallsFunctionWithError = () => {
  functionWithError();
  console.log('This console.log will never be called');
}

functionThatCallsFunctionWithError();
```

Answer (score 0):

### uncomment the super from class Grand

Must call super constructor in derived class before accessing 'this' or returning from derived constructor

```js
class Great {
    constructor() {
        console.log('this is great');
    }
}

class Grand extends Great {
    constructor() {
        super();
        console.log('this is grand');
    }
}

class Father extends Grand {
    constructor() {
        super();
        console.log('I am your father');
    }
}

function main() {
    let dad = new Father();
}

main();
```

Comment: When a normal constructor runs, it creates an empty object and assigns it to this.
But when a derived constructor runs, it doesn’t do this. It expects the parent constructor to do this job. 
So if we’re making a constructor of our own, then we must call super, because otherwise the object for this won’t be created. And we’ll get an error.